# Visual Studio bug or undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The following code works fine with gcc but fails with both Visual Studio 2017 and 2015. I haven't tried any other compilers. The error is run-time rather than compile-time.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

class ListHook
{
};

template<typename Node, ListHook Node::*memberPtr>
struct MemberHookSpec
{
    static ListHook* hookFromNode(Node* node)
    {
        return &(node->*memberPtr);
    }
};

class Object
{
private:
    ListHook m_hook;

public:
    using HookSpec = MemberHookSpec<Object, &Object::m_hook>;

    virtual ~Object() {} // <-- Triggers the issue.

    void verifySameHook(ListHook* hook) const
    {
        bool const same_hook = (&m_hook == hook);
        std::cout << "same hook: " << same_hook << std::endl;
        assert(same_hook);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Object obj;
    obj.verifySameHook(Object::HookSpec::hookFromNode(&obj));
}
```

The expected behaviour is for `same_hook` to be `true`. On Visual Studio it's `false`. Can anyone see undefined behaviour in the code? If not, I am going to report a bug to Microsoft.

Comment: Well, as Visual Studio is an IDE, it's definitely not a bug in Visual Studio. It's code related, so it might be a bug in their C++ compiler, but it's definitely not a bug in VS.

Comment: I can see why a compiler could have trouble with this: computing the offset of the member depends on whether the class has a vtable, and a member type is normally something that can be evaluated immediately in a first pass and does not need complete class information. But all this is implementation details, of course. I don't see anything forbidding this code.

Comment: Looks like a fairly obvious compiler bug. The template obviously returns a pointer to the class instance's `m_hook` member; and whether this class has a virtual destructor, or not, bears no relation to whether a pointer to the this class instance's member compares equal to a pointer to the same class instance's same member.